Hide unwanted options in flutter_custome_tab
I'm currently using flutter_custom_tabs: ^1.2.1 library to launch my url.
But i wanted to hide or remove the action buttons or the unwanted options such as
Share, option, hiding URL etc. Here is the screenshot for better understandings.

my code:
await custom_tab.launch(
    "",
    customTabsOption: custom_tab.CustomTabsOption(
      enableInstantApps: false,
      toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      enableDefaultShare: trur,
      enableUrlBarHiding: true,
      showPageTitle: false,
      animation: custom_tab.CustomTabsSystemAnimation.slideIn(),

      extraCustomTabs: const <String>[
        'org.mozilla.firefox',
        'com.microsoft.emmx',
      ],
    ),

Please give me directions how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance!
